# CSS - Container height same height as parent div unless parent div is smaller than container div

Tags: css, inheritance, height

I currently get the parents div height with: height: inherit;, but when I scale the window down then the parent div is smaller than the container div so overflow: hidden; hides half of the container content.

Is it possible to just do this with css?

This is the code:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="content">
    <div class="wrapper">
        Content here
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#container {
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: red;
}
.content {
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    height: 900px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orymyjto/1/

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to make it do?

Comment: @Lance, I just want the content div to be responsive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the content div min-height: 400px; (replacing height)  So it will never be smaller than the container but can get larger as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You probably use the `overflow` property to clear the floats, right?

Then change `overflow: hidden` to `overflow: auto`.

Comment: this makes the content indeed bigger, but it's scrollable within the container div. But I just want the div to go out of the container div IF it's bigger than the container div (when you resize your window for example)

Comment: Then I don't understand your question :). Can you please clarify? Maybe with some sketches??

Comment: The content div starts with a specific width and height, but if the height of the content div is smaller than the container div then I want it to adopt the height of the container div. IF the height of the content div is larger than the height of the container than it should just use the height of the content div.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Yes, I understand now, the solution is in Lance's answer... :):)